# sed: How can I replace \r\r\n?

Tags: linux, bash, regex, sed

In [this question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n) it is explained how one can replace a newline character using sed.

My problem is that I want to replace the character sequence \r\r\n with sed. Can somebody help me adapt the example given in the referenced question?

Answer (score 2):

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\r\r\n//g'
```

This will replace "\r\n\n" with nothing (that is remove it), while in the example was 
replacing \n with a space so:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\r\r\n/ /g'
```

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that replacing \r\r\n by \n is fairly simple:

```
sed 's/\r\r$//g'
```